# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value, pytorch

Tags: python, json, pytorch

Can somebody please help me out with this problem?

So I was running this code yesterday and it all worked fine. Today, when I run it again, the following error comes up:

---

File "/home/nw432/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

---

Full code available here: https://github.com/jleuschn/dival/blob/483915b2e64c1ad6355311da0429ef8f2c2eceb5/dival/reconstructors/standard_learned_reconstructor.py

Comment: Have you debugged why you aren't getting JSON?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am pretty new to this. What is the best way to do so?

Comment: This is the top of my traceback:

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_26886/2954232242.py", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/nw432/Desktop/dival-master/dival/reconstructors/standard_learned_reconstructor.py', wdir='/home/nw432/Desktop/dival-master/dival/reconstructors')

What does that mean?

Comment: Oh and no matter which code I run, I get this from a lot of scripts